# Reply for Look forward to seeing you tomorrow

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

I would like to reply to a statement *Look forward to seeing you tomorrow*.

Can I write *I look forward too to see you tomorrow?*

OR

*I look forward to see you tomorrow too/as well?*

I would appreciate if anyone could point out the mistake(s) in the above two responses. Also, if the two statements are not correct, what could be the alternative sentence?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: We have [a site search](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=). Please use [the site search](http://english.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=forward%20see%20seeing). Thank you.

Comment: As a side comment, why would you change their wording in the first place? They already spelled out the correct version for you. Then you went and disfigured it for no reason at all. I would not meddle with other people's writing if their command of the language is better than mine.